# Model value is not coming automatically from client as jsaon data

Tags: jquery, json, spring

I have write some sort of code which accept data from user validate it with jquery and then send it to server in form of json. Till client side validation every thing is perfectly fine. but when i move to server side where i use spring controller to get the json value. All model attribute values are null. Even when i saw in client development mode data is going towards server but not fill into model attribute.

my jquery code look like :

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(event){
        var username = $('#id_username').val();  
        var password = $('#id_password').val();
        alert(username + password)
        var json = { "loginId" : username, "password" : password};

      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: $("#login-form").attr("action"),
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            var mess = validateForm();
            if(mess.length != 0){
                $('#error-mes').show();
                $('#error-mes').html(mess);
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return true;
        },
        success: function(response){
             $('#error-mes').html(response);
             $('#error-mes').show();
        },  
        error: function(e){  
          alert('Error: ' + e);  
        }  
      });  
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#userName').hide();
      $('#spn_password').hide();
});
```

And spring conroller looks like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public @ResponseBody String submitCustSignInForm(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("model") Person model,
            HttpSession sess) {

        String response = "";
        Person person = null;

        if (sess.getAttribute("USER_INFO") == null) {
            person = tsService.login(model);
            if (person == null) {
                response = "User name or password does not match.";
            } else {
                response = "success";
                sess.setAttribute("USER_INFO", person);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

and html page looks like:

```
<form class="aui login-form"
     method="post" id="login-form"></form>
```

not posting the entire html form assuming that username text box and password id are same as i used in jquery.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong in this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.server.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="bDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
                hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
                hibernate.show_sql=false
                hibernate.format_sql=true
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <value>objectmodel.hbm.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="bDataSource" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="hibernateTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="tsService" class="com.server.service.TsServiceImpl">
        <property name="dao" ref="dao" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="com.server.dao.DaoSupportImpl" scope="singleton">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplateBean" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="dispatcherDao" class="com.server.servlet.UploadVideoServlet">
        <property name="disDao" ref="dao" />
    </bean>


    <mvc:resources location="./css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
    <mvc:resources location="./js/" mapping="/js/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="./images/" mapping="/images/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="./content/" mapping="/content/**" />

</beans>
```

Comment: post your context configuration

Comment: can u plz tell me why data is not filling automatically into spring model. I also tried to use @RequestBody annotation to get the client data into directly model. But i got the error on client side. 'invalid token character ',' in token "x-www-form-urlencoded,'. can u plz me how to do this.